# Get only the last Date from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects having a DateTime, like this:

```
[{Date1, Count1}, {Date2, Count2}, ...]
```

The Dates in the array are given by Hour (Date2 = Date1 + 1H), so I am interested in taking only the Date's last hour count.

```
{Date: 2020-03-21T20:00:00Z, Count: 3}
{Date: 2020-03-21T22:00:00Z, Count: 4}
{Date: 2020-03-21T23:00:00Z, Count: 15}
{Date: 2020-03-22T00:00:00Z, Count: 66}
{Date: 2020-03-22T01:00:00Z, Count: 70}
```

How can I reduce this Array to take in consideration only the last item of each day?

```
{Date: 2020-03-21T23:00:00Z, Count: 15}
{Date: 2020-03-22T01:00:00Z, Count: 70}
```

Something like `myArray.groupBy(Date).TakeLast()`...

Comment: What do you mean by The `Dates in the array are given by Hour` ? Can you add more details.

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: let's say yes, is guaranteed to be sorted

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that only works if the dates are sorted (if they're not you can just sort via `dates.sort((a, b) => a.Date.getTime() - b.Date.getTime())`:

```
var dates = [
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T20:00:00Z"), Count: 3 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T22:00:00Z"), Count: 4 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T23:00:00Z"), Count: 15 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-22T00:00:00Z"), Count: 66 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-22T01:00:00Z"), Count: 70 }
];
var lastPerDay = [];
// just need to set to a value that's impossible to get normally
var prevDate = null;
// go backwards through the array to find the last instance
for (var i = dates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // need some way of combining year, month, and date into a value
    var curDate = [dates[i].Date.getUTCFullYear(), dates[i].Date.getUTCMonth(), dates[i].Date.getUTCDate()].join(",");
    // we haven't seen the date before
    if (curDate !== prevDate) {
        // add the day to the front
        lastPerDay.unshift(dates[i]);
        // update the previous date
        prevDate = curDate;
    }
}
console.log(lastPerDay);
```

Comment: OP: "let's say yes, is guaranteed to be sorted"

Comment: I am wondering also the old solution when I just take the last element by date, no matter if it's the last or not hour (so, supposed sorted)

Comment: the Date in Javascript has a function `.ToDateString()`, theres no need to extract years months etc

Comment: `.toDateString` returns the date string adjusted for the local timezone, which I'm not sure is what you want judging by your sample cases.

Answer (score 0):

With this, there is no need for the dates to be sorted.

```js
let lastsHour = {}, array = [
  { date: new Date("2020-03-21T20:00:00Z"), count: 3 },
  { date: new Date("2020-03-21T22:00:00Z"), count: 4 },
  { date: new Date("2020-03-21T23:00:00Z"), count: 15 },
  { date: new Date("2020-03-22T00:00:00Z"), count: 66 },
  { date: new Date("2020-03-22T01:00:00Z"), count: 70 }
];


array.map(function (e) {

  let currentDate = ""+e.date.getUTCDate()+e.date.getUTCMonth()+e.date.getUTCFullYear();

  if (! lastsHour[currentDate]) {

    lastsHour[currentDate] = e;

  } else if (lastsHour[currentDate].date < e.date) {

    lastsHour[currentDate] = e;
  }
});

let result = [];
for (let key in lastsHour ) {
  if (lastsHour.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    result.push(lastsHour[key]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Serge You'll have to extract the objects and put them back in an array, but it's the last object (and the last count) of each date.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reduce` method and decide on each iteration whether it is a next hour of current day. Then we can delete an array element which contains previous hour. We have `O(N)` by using `reduce` method:

```
const oneHourInMilliseconds = 3600000;
const result = arr.reduce((a, {Date: date, Count}) => {
  let [y, m, d] = date.split(/\D+/);
  let key = new Date(date).getTime();
  a[key] = a[key] || { Date: date, Count };
  if (a[key - oneHourInMilliseconds]) {
    let [yPrev, mPrev, dPrev] = a[key - oneHourInMilliseconds].Date.split(/\D+/);
    if (d == dPrev)
        delete a[key-oneHourInMilliseconds];
  }
  return a;
},{})
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  {Date : '2020-03-21T22:00:00Z', Count: 4},
  {Date : '2020-03-21T23:00:00Z', Count: 15},
  {Date : '2020-03-22T00:00:00Z', Count: 66},
  {Date : '2020-03-22T01:00:00Z', Count: 70},
];

const oneHourInMilliseconds = 3600000;
const result = arr.reduce((a, {Date: date, Count}) => {
  let [y, m, d] = date.split(/\D+/);
  let key = new Date(date).getTime();
  a[key] = a[key] || { Date: date, Count };
  if (a[key - oneHourInMilliseconds]) {
    let [yPrev, mPrev, dPrev] = a[key - oneHourInMilliseconds].Date.split(/\D+/);
    if (d == dPrev)
        delete a[key-oneHourInMilliseconds];
  }
  return a;
},{})
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T20:00:00Z"), Count: 3 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T22:00:00Z"), Count: 4 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-21T23:00:00Z"), Count: 15 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-22T00:00:00Z"), Count: 66 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-22T01:00:00Z"), Count: 70 },
    { Date: new Date("2020-03-22T20:00:00Z"), Count: 170 }    
];

var filtered = items.filter((e, i, arr) => {
    return (i == arr.length - 1 || 
      arr[i].Date.toDateString() != arr[i + 1].Date.toDateString());
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: It won't work in all timezone.  In mine, this code only give one line as result.

Comment: but this is not a problem... it should display the results based on your day, not the Greenwitch one;) just adjust the initial data to your timeline to switchth e day

Comment: @DominiqueFortin, updated now should work in your timezone as well ;)